# When to call openDrawer() (or any other animation) to make it visible on startup?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I want my app to show the side navigation drawer as soon as the main activity is created.
My code works fine - user launches app and gets the open drawer - but I'd like to actually *see* the side drawer sliding from the left; instead, I find the drawer fully opened.

At what point should I call `openDrawer()`?
Have tried calling from:

- main activity OnCreate;
- similar points in the fragment hosted by the drawer.

I could try OnPrepareOptionsMenu, but I think it gets called more than once during the activity lifecycle. I also tried OnStart() and I fear my options are over.
Any idea? I'm sure this is pretty simple but I can't figure out.

**Edit**: I realize I wasn't so clear with my first exposition of the question (@Biu). I'm talking about a purely graphical issue here. The point is:

- I have something to happen at startup; in my case we're speaking about the nav drawer sliding into the main screen, but it could be any animation I think;
- In my case, one could just call:

  ```
  protected void OnCreate(Bundle b) {
  ...
  DrawerLayout.openDrawer()
  }
  ```
- The above solution works well. The issue I'm talking about is graphical; with the above code you launch the app and find the main activity covered with an *already-opened* drawer. Instead, I'd like the user to have clue of what is happing, to see where the panel came from; in other words, to see the opening animation.

So my question is: when should I call `openDrawer()`? The main Activity onCreate isn't quite right, because the animation ends before the user gets to see something on screen.

I thought that the wish of having something *start* when all is loaded would be more common.

Comment: Android's user knows about sliding menu, it is known UI pattern for it. So you don't need to implement such kind of behavior at your application.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Anyway, I'd like to know when to call anything to make it start when the user launches the app and the UI is (at least partially) loaded.

Comment: Use a handler and post a runnable which calls opendrawer().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@benjosantony suggests that you should open your drawer at `onResume`, however it's not guaranteed that the activity will be visible at that time:

> onResume is not the best indicator that your
>   activity is visible to the user; Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain
>   that your activity is visible to the user

You'd think that you can just use `onWindowFocusChanged` and be done, but you can't. There's still the transition animation which breaks (at least for me) the drawer's animation..

**For API 21+:** 
There's `onEnterAnimationComplete` where you can open your drawer and see the animation properly. However 21+ is a requirement that's just too big..

**For lower APIs:**
The only possible way I can think of is removing the activity's animation with a theme adjustment:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

And opening the drawer like so:

```
private static final String DRAWER_STATE = "mDrawerOpened";
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private boolean mDrawerOpened;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (!mDrawerOpened && hasFocus) {
        mDrawer.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        mDrawerOpened = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(DRAWER_STATE, mDrawerOpened);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerOpened = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(DRAWER_STATE);
}
```

This will animate the drawer only when the activity is started.

The boolean value is saved when your activity is destroyed abnormally, e.g. rotation or need for system resources.

If you don't like setting the instanceState you can use `SharedPreferences` as @Biu suggested, however IMO that wouldn't be the proper solution as android already provides tools for that, there's no need to re-invent the bike.

Comment: `onWindowFocusChanged` works fine, thank you. Out of curiosity, could you explain what `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` are about?

Comment: @miav as I've said, `when your activity is destroyed abnormally, e.g. rotation or need for system resources` onSaveInstanceState is called. As it's name implies, it simply saves the state of this specific instance of the activity and later when needed it restores it (onRestoreInstanceState). Basically it's used when activity is destroyed but will (might) be re-created soon with the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this hack by using `SharedPreferences`

```
 boolean firstTime = true;

 SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
 {
     if (pref.getBoolean("firstTime", true) == true)
     {
          drawer.openDrawer(yourDrawer);
          firstTime = false;
          pref.editor().putBoolean("firstTime", firstTime).apply();
     }
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing built-in that could do that for you, you have to implement it yourself, that is why it is said, there is nothing you cant do in Android, you just have to figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: I don't get your answer though. Is this a way to make it run just the first time? I already managed to do that. I'm trying to call openDrawer() in such a way that the user can *see* the panel sliding from the side of the screen.

Comment: I have changed the answer slightly to use a boolean flag to more accurately reflect the intention here. The reason why I used `SharedPreferences` is because unless your app is uninstalled, anything you saved to it is persist across sessions no matter what. So if this is the first your app is used, then the `firstTime` is true, so we check it in the `onCreate()` method, then we set that flag to `false` indicating that the user has known of the existence of the drawer, so the next time it wont automatically open anymore.

Answer (score -1):

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user.

**Thus I think onResume is the best place to open your drawer.**

Comment: From what I read onResume() would be called if I, say, switch to Activity2 and then back to main Activity. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: of course it will be called. What you asked was when to call openDrawer() so that the user can see the animation. That place is onResume. And you could simply set some boolean to avoid opening drawer if the behaviour is already displayed. (That is onResume being called after coming back from another activity).

Comment: I see. Sadly even onResume() it's not enough, I find the drawer already opened. Might be due to my old device.

Comment: May be run a CountDownTimer onResume , say for 1 second and then on onFinish of CountDownTimer you open the drawer. Just give a few tries do decide on the right amount of time the counter should run until you see the desired effect

Comment: But just be careful using the CountDownTimer to make sure it only runs as desired. (Handle the situations like open activity and nav immediate to another activity and comeback to the mainActivity causing the the timer to run twice).